# Setting up qTip2 to work with any dynamically added tooltip to a page

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I have a prototype with 2 tooltip triggers, each opening its respective tooltip, but the tooltip must stay open on click. Each tooltip has a close link to to close the tooltip.

In my first prototype, I got this to work for a single tooltip trigger, but going forward, I wanted to make it more global to support any tooltip on any page, even if there are more than one tooltip on a page.

I am having problems getting the tooltip to display. I debugged my code and followed it all the way through. The qTip2 code picks up each trigger and its respective tooltip content, but on click of the trigger, does not display it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/donmarais/mVDZ3/1/

```
      $(function() { 
var closeTooltipIds = [],
    closeTooltipId,
    openTooltipIds = [],
    openTooltipId = $('a.tooltip-open');

$('a.tooltip-open').each( function() {
    // First get the ID's of all the anchor tags with the class tooltip-open and add them to the opentooltipids array
    var eachTooltipOpenId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    openTooltipIds.push(eachTooltipOpenId);  

    // Next, iterate through each opentooltip id and add a tooltip
    $(openTooltipIds).each(function(i) { 
        var el = $(this);
        el.qtip({ 
            content: {
                text: $(this).next()
            },
            events: {
                visible: function() {
                    $('.tooltip-close').focus()
                }
            },
            position: {
                my: 'center left',  
                at: 'center right',
                target: $(this) 
            },
            show: {
                event: 'click'
            },
            hide: false
        });

        // Now get a reference to each open tooltip trigger id and find its respective tooltip's close link and get its id.
        closeTooltipId = '#' + $(openTooltipIds[i]).next('.tooltip').find('a.tooltip-close').attr('id');
        // add the ids to the closetooltip array
        closeTooltipIds.push(closeTooltipId);
    });  
});

// Bind the close event to each anchor tag in the closeTooltipIds array
$.each( closeTooltipIds, function( intValue, currentCloseTooltipId ) {
    // Bind the close event to each anchor tag in the closeTooltipIds array
    $(currentCloseTooltipId).bind('click', function() {
        var qTipContainer = $(currentCloseTooltipId).closest('.qtip');
        $(qTipContainer).hide();
    }); 
});
```

});

Comment: The reason I'm storing the tooltip trigger id is so that when you close the tooltip, I can move focus back to it. I am building keyboard accessibility into the prototype.

Comment: So I managed to solve my problem. I built a new fiddle to demonstrate: jsfiddle.net/donmarais/mVDZ3/3/

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I completed the prototype with keyboard accessibility built in. I've tested it in IE and with JAWS 15. It captures focus on the close link within the tooltip once opened and returns focus to the trigger. It also captures the tab key, shift+tab key, and the escape key. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/donmarais/mVDZ3/4/

Comment: I also tested in FF with NVDA. Passes that test as well.